# Newly installed Geogebra doesn't open (persumably JDK issue)

Tags: java, geogebra

Just now installed `geogebra` on my Ubuntu 16.04 (with plain old `sudo apt-get install geogebra`)

when I try to open it I get:

```
GeoGebra 4.0.34.0 (Debian version 4.0.34.0+dfsg1-3) 22 June 2012 Java 9-internal
*** Message from [geogebra.main.Application.setUpLogging]
/tmp/GeoGebraLog_hltazoiolj.txt
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9a380b8009, pid=25913, tid=25915
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to /mnt/storage/programs/linux/installers/core.25913)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /mnt/storage/programs/linux/installers/hs_err_pid25913.log
[thread 25945 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I guess it has to do with my JDK, but I have no actual clue what to do. my `java -version` output:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using Java 9?

Comment: IDK really, I installed the generic openJDK9 Ubuntu has to offer. Sould I use something else and it'll work?

Comment: Java 9 isn't officially released so I highly doubt any major Java app is using it yet. I don't know how you got that setup, but I would recommend you install JDK 8 instead.

Comment: I basically have both installed. my `/etc/environment` says `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"`.
I tried changing it to `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"` (and then `source`) but it didn't help. I guess it wasn't were jdk9 is set to begin with as it said 1.8... So where should I set the JDK 8 to run by default?

Comment: Not sure why you need to edit either file yourself. `update-java-alternatives` should be available as a command

Comment: Thanks, googled how to use the `update-alternatives` -> chose JDK8 -> opened `geogebra`. You can have the honour of posting your solution and I'll confirm it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 9 isn't officially released so I highly doubt any major Java app is using it yet. I don't know how you got that setup, but I would recommend you install JDK 8 instead

`update-java-alternatives` should be available as a command (depending on your OS), but after you install JDK 8, you can run that and select it to set Java 8 as the Java version for your system.

Or you could edit `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` yourself, but I wouldn't recommend it when there's easier / safer ways.